# How do I get the Key of a HashTable entry WITHOUT foreach?

Tags: c#

I can enumerate through the entries in a HashTable with

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in ht)
```

but I want to know what the key is for entry x. Something like:

```
DictionaryEntry de = ht[0]; // this does NOT return DictionaryEntry - it return the object with key 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashTable` doesn't work that way.

You'd have to create a second hash table or dictionary that maps the other direction.  Otherwise you have to use a `foreach`, like you did in your question.

Comment: I removed the code I had because it wouldn't actually solve the problem (oops).  You need two dictionaries to solve this, or to live with the perf of `foreach`.